# Android Instrumented testing asserting if an activity is started

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-espresso, instrumented-test

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin programming language. I am adding instrumentation tests into my application. Now I am trying to test if an activity is started after some delay.

This is my activity code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        val LAUNCH_DELAY: Long = 2000
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Handler().postDelayed({
            this.startLoginActivity()
        }, LAUNCH_DELAY)
    }

    protected fun startLoginActivity()
    {
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

I know how to write a simple test like this

```kotlin
@Test
fun itRendersCompanyName() {
    onView(withId(R.id.main_tv_company_name)).check(matches(withText("App Name")))
}
```

But what I am trying to test here is if the LoginActivity is launched after some delay. How can I do it using Espresso framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Intents.intended()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/intent/Intents#intended) for that.

Add following to your **build.gradle** file:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'
```

In your test function, you can try following code:

```
Intents.init()
Intents.intended(hasComponent(LoginActivity::class.java!!.getName()))
```

You can read more about Espresso-Intents [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents).

Comment: Hi Natig, there are three different Intents in my project. Which one do I have to use.  None of them has intented method in it.

Comment: Would you be able to specify the full class name or namespace, please?

Comment: You have to add  `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'` to your app level build.gradle file.

Comment: This is class name with package name: `androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents`

Comment: Don't forget to add Thread.sleep(2000) before calling intended() function as your action will be executed after 2 seconds according to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I got another issue. Please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049150/android-kotlin-expresso-asserting-intended-activity-in-the-unit-test-is-throwing

Comment: Have you tried adding Thread.sleep(2000) before calling Intents.intended() ?

Comment: Hi that is completely different issue. I removed the delay.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll check.

Comment: To get null pointer exception, you can put Intents.init() before Intents.intended.

Comment: Would you be able to post the answer on the other question please?

Comment: I also updated the question because I got another issue after I use init()

Comment: I used your answer, I got anther issue.

Comment: Ok. I’ll check that as well.

Comment: I added fix in that new question

Answer (score 4):

You can get the visible Activity using `ActivityManager`:

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> isVisible(): Boolean {
    val am = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)
            as ActivityManager

    val visibleActivityName = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        am.appTasks[0].taskInfo.topActivity.className
    } else {
        am.getRunningTasks(1)[0].topActivity.className
    }
    return visibleActivityName == T::class.java.name
}
```

Calling `isVisible<LoginActivity>()` will tell you that `LoginActivity` is visible or not.

Also, to wait until your `LoginActivity` visible, you can wait for this method to gets `true`. For example:

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> waitUntilActivityVisible() {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    while (!isVisible<T>()) {
        Thread.sleep(200)
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= TIMEOUT) {
            throw AssertionError("Condition unsatisfied after $TIMEOUT milliseconds")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend checking for null in appTasks getter: val visibleActivityName = am.appTasks.elementAtOrNull(0)?.taskInfo?.baseActivity?.className

Answer (score 1):

It’s better to test this state with unit tests. Use architecture pattern (for example MVP/MVVM), mock presenter/view model and check what method which is responsible for activity start is triggered

Comment: How to test if a method is triggered in android?

Comment: Mockito.verify(mockedClass).someMethod(parameters)

Comment: for example: in @Before:

presenter = Mockito.spy(SomePresenter(...))

in test:
Mockito.verify(presenter, times(1)).startLoginActivity()

where times(1) mean what is was exactly one interaction

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following:

```
val expectedUrl = "https://yoururlhere"    
Intents.init();
Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW), hasData(expectedUrl));
intending(expectedIntent).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(0, null));
onView(withId(R.id.someViewId)).perform(click());
intended(expectedIntent);
Intents.release();
```

And remember to add "androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'" to your gradle dependency