# Android Kotlin Espresso asserting intended activity in the unit test is throwing error

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-espresso, instrumented-test

I am developing an Android application. I am adding instrumented tests to my application and testing if an activity is launched using Espresso. But I am getting error in asserting that an activity is launched using the Espresso test framework.

I added the following express packages into my app gradle

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$expressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$expressoVersion"
```

This is my activity class

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        startLoginActivity()
    }

    protected fun startLoginActivity()
    {
        startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

This is my test method

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest {
    @Rule @JvmField
    val mainActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun itStartsLoginActivityAfterDelay() {
        Intents.intended(hasComponent(LoginActivity::class.java!!.name))
    }
}
```

When I run my test, I got the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(org.hamcrest.Matcher, androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode, java.util.List)' on a null object reference
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:193)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:419)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:282)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

I tried changing my code to the following to get rid of the Null exception

```
Intents.init()
        Intents.intended(hasComponent(LoginActivity::class.java!!.name))
```

Then I got this error

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "com.example.memento.LoginActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:94)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:57)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:318)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:300)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:189)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:170)
at com.example.memento.MainActivityTest.itStartsLoginActivityAfterDelay(MainActivityTest.kt:44)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:531)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: has component: has component with: class name: is "com.example.memento.LoginActivity" package name: an instance of java.lang.String short class name: an instance of java.lang.String

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationModes$Times.verify(VerificationModes.java:80)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(Intents.java:346)
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:193)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:419)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:282)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mainActivityRule.launchActivity(Intent())` should fix the issue.

```
@Test
fun itStartsLoginActivityAfterDelay() {
    Intents.init()
    mainActivityRule.launchActivity(Intent())
    Intents.intended(hasComponent(Main2Activity::class.java.name))
    Intents.release()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be `Intents.intended(hasComponent(MainActivity::class.java!!.name))`, according to `ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>`. It's probably useless to start the `MainActivitiy`, when intending to test the `LoginActivity`.

Comment: But I am testing that if the main activity starts login activity. How can I test it then?

Comment: @WaiYanHein with `UiAutomator2` this might be easier, because one can let it wait for an `Activity` to be launched.